# How to make responsive content with React and Material UI?

Tags: html, reactjs, responsive-design, material-ui

I'm designing a product detail page with React and Material UI. I tried to make the page responsive. But the description section keeps overlapping over the image until the screen is reduced to the mobile size. The content gets stacked at that point, but the images and text are not adjusting to the screen size.

I feel like it's something wrong with the image styling. How do I get the images to be responsive?

Here's my code

`styling section`

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
  },
  toolbar: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
    // necessary for content to be below app bar
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
  },
}));
```

`function`

```
export default function ProductDetails() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <main className={classes.content}>
      <div className={classes.toolbar} />

      <Grid container spacing={3}> {/* image and description container */}
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}> {/* image container */}
          <Grid> {/* preview image */}
            <img src="luxury-watch.jpg" width="600" id="preview" alt="" />
          </Grid>
          <Grid> {/* sub images */}
            <img src="luxury-watch.jpg" width="140" id="img1" alt="" />
            <img src="luxury-watch.jpg" width="140" id="img2" alt="" />
            <img src="luxury-watch.jpg" width="140" id="img3" alt="" />
            <img src="luxury-watch.jpg" width="140" id="img4" alt="" />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}> {/* description container */}
          <div>
            <h1>ROLEX</h1>
            <p> .... </p>
            <h2><span><sup>$</sup></span>1250</h2>
            <Button variant="contained" color="secondary">ADD TO CART</Button>
          </div>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've  missed a few props on your `Grid` elements. Try this:

```
export default function ProductDetails() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <main className={classes.content}>
      <div className={classes.toolbar} />

      <Grid container spacing={3}> {/* image and description container */}
        <Grid item container xs={12} sm={6}> {/* image container */}
          <Grid item> {/* preview image */}
            <img src="luxury-watch.jpg" width="600" id="preview" alt="" />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item> {/* sub images */}
            <img src="luxury-watch.jpg" width="140" id="img1" alt="" />
            <img src="luxury-watch.jpg" width="140" id="img2" alt="" />
            <img src="luxury-watch.jpg" width="140" id="img3" alt="" />
            <img src="luxury-watch.jpg" width="140" id="img4" alt="" />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>

        <Grid item container xs={12} sm={6}> {/* description container */}
          <div>
            <h1>ROLEX</h1>
            <p> .... </p>
            <h2><span><sup>$</sup></span>1250</h2>
            <Button variant="contained" color="secondary">ADD TO CART</Button>
          </div>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </main>
  );
}
```

You can't apply `xs` attribute if your `Grid` items isn't a `container` and you console should be warning you about that too

Answer (score 0):

You can use material ui breakpoints for responsiveness

```html
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
  },
  toolbar: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
    // necessary for content to be below app bar
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
    [theme.breakpoints.down('lg')]:{
      width:'60%',
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.up('lg')]:{
      width:'60%',
    }
  }
}));
```